# Using redux-saga with @reduxjs/toolkit, Trying to use Provider but it is not working. How to use Provider in this case

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

**Here is the code sample. I can't use Provider here in react native**

```
const configureStore = () => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  
    const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

  
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: createReducer(),
      middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware({thunk: false}), ...middlewares],
    });
    
    sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
  
    return store;
  }

  export default configureStore ;



export default function Main() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      
        <App />
      
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**But if I use below code Provider is not giving error**

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
          
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];
const store = configureStore({
     reducer: createReducer(),
     middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware({thunk: false}), ...middlewares],
    });
    
export default store;
```

Please help me to use Provider wrapper

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: There is some context missing from both examples as well - where do you call `configureStore()` to get the store itself in the first example? And where do you call `sagaMiddleware.run(...);` in the second example?